# How to check dynamic class usage in very big java project

Tags: java, profiling, code-coverage

I have a pretty big Java project with very low code coverage, and want to increase the number of test cases. Is there any way to measure which classes are used the most in runtime? This way we can measure which classes we need to cover first. The project is a web app running over tomcat & websphere if it is important.

Comment: this might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8449870/is-there-any-tool-to-detect-code-functionality-which-is-no-longer-used/8449914#8449914

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, but I think you're going about it the wrong way. Your classes that get used the most might end up being boilerplate classes or plumbing classes. I'd be much more concerned about `CustomerDiscountFactory` than `OrderXMLMarshaller`, even if the xml gets used more than the discounts, I would feel it's not as important to test. Build your list of functionality as to what you feel needs the testing the most from a logic perspective and a knowledge of the system, not from what happens to get run most often. Just my take :-)

Comment: @glowcoder: I was just going to say the same. Highly relevant code has fewer "subtle" bugs than irrelevant remote business logic.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39329/what-is-your-favourite-code-coverage-tools-free-and-non-free

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idea behind code coverage is not to cover as much code as possible but to **cover the code that is most expensive for you**.

So a good start is to look at your bug database: Is there a place in the code that shows up often? Or do you know a piece of code where you're first thought is "I don't want to touch that ... **ever**"

Ask your colleagues about weak spots. Every project has them and everyone knows about them; it's just that nobody dares to venture there.

These are excellent places to start with test cases because those are the places where the missing coverage *hurts*.

Rationale: There is no point to test code that works. Code that is executed often usually works because bugs were found quickly and there was a lot of pressure to fix them.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

There are tools that replace the standard Classloader so that they instrument classes for coverage as those classes are loaded.

I think that Clover and Emma were the best ones that I've used. Emma is free, but doesn't appear to be very active since 2005.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative approach will be to "profile" the application and walk through the various workflows with profiler on. 
You can then sort on loaded classes, method invocations (with count) to get an idea of what classes are used the most.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on server setting you can atatch external profiling tool  (there is a lot) to process. You cal also get some first insights via jConsole  tool provided with JDK.  But my favorite is carefull look into  sources or webapp statistics to determine  possible most used classes. Ultimately, you will have to test all of them.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into AOP? Basically you write some 'aspects' and the AOP runtime weaves them with classes you specified. Totally non-intrusive. One application of AOP **is** coverage test. If you go down this way, you can check out [Spring AOP](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/aop-api.html).

Answer (score 0):

Ask a developer who's familiar with the system which parts are the most problematic (as in, produce the most bugs, have to be changed often, are the hardest to add features to, etc). The answer will be far more useful than any numerical measurement.

Comment: That is a good way, but it presupposes that such a developer exists...which is more likely than not, false in most poor code bases.

Comment: @Chii: I'd say that's a worst case scenarion that's quite rare. There may often not be any developer who's worked on the system since its inception, but ususally several who have worked on it for at least a few months, and that's enough to get an idea where the problematic areas are.